# Application shutdown in MonoMac

Tags: c#, exit, monomac

I'm trying to shutdown a MonoMac application by using `Environment.Exit(0)`. However, this call for some reason does not return. It does not throw an exception, either. When I execute the function in the immediate window in MonoDevelop, it times out.

I have no idea how to approach debugging this. I thought that Environment.Exit kills the process...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [NSApplication.Terminate](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M:MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Terminate%28MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject%29) method instead.

Note that this method may call the application delegate (if defined) to confirm the termination (See [NSApplicationDelegate.ApplicationShouldTerminate](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M:MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplicationDelegate.ApplicationShouldTerminate%28MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication%29)).

Comment: Sweet, that worked perfectly. I called `NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(this)` in my controller.

Answer (score 3):

You may add two override functions in AppDelegate.cs.

```
public override NSApplicationTerminateReply ApplitionShouldTerminate(NSApplication sender) 
{
    mainWindowController.Window.Close();
    return NSApplicationTerminateReply.Now;
}

public override bool ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(NSApplication sender)
{
    return true;
}
```